# Is there an online service which provides the same functionalities as the Metasploit NASM shell?

Tags: shellcode, metasploit, nasm

Does anyone know if there exists an online service which provides the same functionalities as the [Metasploit NASM shell](https://github.com/Rendered79/metasploit/blob/master/tools/nasm_shell.rb) ?

Probably the above script can be ported to a standalone tool but I'm not very confident with Ruby, so if someone knows something already implemented, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several online tools providing a disassembling service. Here is a (non-exhaustive) list:

- [ODAweb](http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/) (probably the most known);
- [Pym's online disassembler](http://pyms86.appspot.com/);
- [PVPHP](http://code.google.com/p/pvphp/);
- [Udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/);
- [Defuse online x86 assembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm) (a bit out-of-topic, but we never know).

Comment: The first three tools focuses on disassembling a given sets of opcodes. The Defuse online x86 assembler allows to assemble x86 instructions and translate them in opcodes, wich is exactly what the Metasploit script provides and what I was looking for. Thanks.